# How to draw 3 million circles in python

Tags: python, memory, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I've got a dataset of many (~3M) circles (each has an `x`, `y`, and `od` property) in a pandas dataframe. I'd like to plot them over each other to visualize patterns

I had done this previously with a smaller dataset (about 15k circles), but now it seems to be choking (memory is going up to the 16GB by the time I'm at only a few hundred thousand)

`df` is the dataframe
`plt` is `matplotlib.pyplot`

```
ax2=plt.gca(xlim=(-.25,.25),ylim=(-0.25,0.25))

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    x=row.X_delta
    y=row.Y_delta
    od=float(row.OD)
    circle=plt.Circle((x,y),od/2,color='r',fill=False,lw=5,alpha=0.01)
    ax2.add_artist(circle)
```

Any thoughts on a more memory efficient way to do this?

Comment: Question: why would you want to draw 3 million circles anyway? what information does this give you?

Comment: Could you compute which circles will be completely overlapped by others and skip drawing those?

Comment: Instead of invoking the "Circle" patch, can you just draw a scatterplot? I believe that will be much more memory-efficient.  Note that you can provide a list of sizes to the "s" argument, so as far as I can see there's nothing in the "Circle" patch that you can't get from a scatterplot.

Comment: what information do you hope to get from this? I'd suggest running e.g. kmeans on it before you start plotting.

Comment: @edChum, the variation in the circle position and diameter is large enough relative to the resolution I care about that the overlap of the circles in certain places (you will notice that they are transparent) is very telling. If there's no clever way to handle them all in memory I'll have to bin or deduplicate, which I'd like to avoid if I could due to the loss of fidelity.

Comment: @iayork I can't seem to figure out how to pass scatterplot and explicit area size (to get at my explicit diameter)

Answer (score 2):

Drawing all 3 million circles in one plot doesn't seem a viable approach. Here's an example with just 1000 circles (following the [example by matt_s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33655691/890242)):

[image: 1000 circles overlapped]

Instead, I suggest to reduce the number of circles to draw to some sensible value, e.g. 50 or 100. One approach is to run [KMeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means) on your dataset to cluster the circles by coordinate and diameter. The following chart represents the clustering of 100'000 random circles as an example. This should easily scale to 3 million circles.

The marker's dimensions represent the diameter (`s`, scaled to fit the chart), and the color indicates the number of circles per cluster center (`c`). YMMV

[image]

Code used to plot the first chart (ipython)

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
n = 1000
circles = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.random(n), 'y': np.random.random(n), 'r': np.random.random(n)},)
circles.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', s=circles['r']*1000, c=circles.r * 10, facecolors='none')
```

Code used to plot the second chart (ipython)

```
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# parameters
n = 100000
n_clusters = 50
# dummy data
circles = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.random(n), 'y': np.random.random(n), 'r': np.random.random(n)})
# cluster using kmeans
km = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, n_jobs=-2)
circles['cluster'] = pd.Series(km.fit_predict(circles.as_matrix()))
# bin by cluster
cluster_size = circles.groupby('cluster').cluster.count()
# plot, using #circles / per cluster as the od weight
clusters = km.cluster_centers_
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.scatter(x=clusters[:,0], y=clusters[:,1], # clusters x,y
                 c=cluster_size, #color
                 s=clusters[:,2] * 1000, #diameter, scaled
                 facecolors='none') # don't fill markers
plt.colorbar()
fig.suptitle('clusters by #circles, c/d = size')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the pandas scatter plot?

```
import pandas as pd
import random

n = 100000
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.random(n), 'y': np.random.random(n), 'r': np.random.random(n)})
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='x', y='y', s=df['r']*1000, facecolor='none')
```

Comment: I don't think I can... I should have mentioned that I want these circles to be hollow (i.e. rings)

Comment: You can set facecolors='none'

Comment: That should be facecolor singular ;-)

Comment: Ahhh... another tricky thing with the scatterplot seems to be the inability to draw circles with an absolute diameter.